# Adding active class with jQuery working incorrectly

Tags: jquery

I have the following code that I am trying to get an active class to be added to the navigation selector if it matches the current URL. It works fine with the exception of when I go on the first link and because the URL is contained in all of the other elements below it, it adds the active class to all of them. If I click in to the other pages they work correctly as they should.

I'm sure it is something simple that I've missed but haven't been able to work it out yet!

```
  <script>
    jQuery(function(){
      var current = location.pathname;
      jQuery("#partner-menu li a").each(function(){
        var jQuerythis = jQuery(this);
        if(jQuerythis.attr("href").indexOf(current) !== -1){
          jQuerythis.addClass("active");
        }
      })
    })
  </script>

  <nav>
    <ul id="partner-menu" >
      <li ><a href="https://www.website.com/partner-dashboard/" class="partner-link">Dashboard</a></li>
      <li ><a href="https://www.website.com/partner-dashboard/sales-statistics/"  class="partner-link">Sales Statistics</a></li>
      <li ><a href="https://www.website.com/partner-dashboard/orders/" class="partner-link" >Orders</a></li>
      <li ><a href="https://www.website.com/partner-dashboard/projects/" class="partner-link" >Projects</a></li>
    </ul> </nav>
```

Comment: Hi, you can try like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/x3hroe16/) i.e : simply break out of each loop when condition met .

Comment: When you visit the first page, the pathname is `/partner-dashboard`, this value return true for all 4 <a> instances. So the class is added to all nav. Just build the whole url and compare with reference link of <a>